# Issue importing Excel into SQL using IIS App pool

Tags: excel, iis

I have written a web app in asp.net that will import data from an excel spreadsheet to SQL (code below). If I run it from VS on my local machine using IIS Express it works fine. However, when I deploy it as a web app on our Azure web server as an IIS App Pool, it is only importing part of the data from excel (16250 rows out of 73,000). I have the app pool set to enable 32 bit applications (the microsoft.ace.oledb library on that server is 32 bit). I found the last record it loaded in SQL (it only partially loaded the row) and moved that to the top of the excel spreadsheet and re-imported. That record imported fine this time but still only got partial import into SQL (16219 rows this time). So it appears the data is OK but I cannot figure out why it is not loading all the data. I do not get any errors when running the process.

Code:

```
       string excelstring = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.16.0;data source=" + rptpath + filename +
                              ";extended properties=" + "\"excel 12.0;hdr=yes;\"";


        try
        {
            OleDbConnection oledbconnection = new OleDbConnection();
            oledbconnection.ConnectionString = excelstring;
            oledbconnection.Open();

            DataTable dtSheet = oledbconnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
            {
                sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            }

            sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetname + "]";

            OleDbCommand oledbcommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlstring, oledbconnection);
            oledbcommand.CommandTimeout = 240;
            DbDataReader dr = oledbcommand.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(connsql);
            bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = tablename;
            bulkInsert.BulkCopyTimeout = 240;

            bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);

            oledbconnection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "showError", "alert('" + Ex.Message + "');", true);
            errormessage = Ex.Message;
            return "error";
        }
```

Comment: From the code you provided, it is difficult to see where the problem is. Including your description of the problem, the application itself does not report an error, and it is not easy to find the cause of the problem.
I suggest you use the debug diagnostic tool to grab the dump information of the app pool, and then analyze the data to find out the problem. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924

Comment: You can try to insert an excel with less data and a smaller file to see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Yes I tried a smaller excel file and it worked fine. So that seems to indicate some type of issue on the server/app pool settings perhaps? I am contacting our cloud architect to see if he can trace what is happening.

Comment: I think it may be a server performance problem. If your cloud architect finds a solution, you can post it.